# Launch new Hangouts Dialer from an Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

With the release of the new Hangouts app (2.3) and the Hangouts Dialer, I was wondering if anyone knew how to trigger the dialer from an intent. When you use the standard Intent.ACTION_CALL or Intent.ACTION_DIAL I don't get the new Hangouts Dialer in the list.

Is there a different intent type or URI that anyone has found that would allow me to start a call from my app on the new Hangouts Dialer directly?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Tried with Hangouts v2.5.8xxxx

Intent.ACTION_DIAL is the intent filter for Hangouts.